# facebook auto loging using php

Tags: php

i want to make a auto loggin app using this but there's no result.
is curl the best choice. and how can i pass my id and password because this isn't working.

```
            $fields = array(
                "email" => "email",
        "password" => "PASS",
    );

        function curl($url,$fields)
        {
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
                { 
                    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
                    }
            rtrim($fields_string, '&');
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
            $ip=rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2");
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");

            $page = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $page;
        }

        $res=curl('https://fr-fr.facebook.com?',$fields);

        echo $res;''''
```

Comment: Why not use their [PHP-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)?

Comment: Facebook does not want you to do anything like that, and they of course have measures in place to recognize naive attempts like this. Use the available APIs, if you feel like you need to “automate” anything regarding getting data from or creating content on Facebook.